# Why does my Node.js server echo back everything I send to it from nc?

Tags: node.js, netcat, unix-socket

I am new to Node.js and I'm trying to learn by building a server that listens to a Unix-domain socket.  I'm testing my server using 'nc' as a client.  'nc -U /var/run/ipc.sock'  Everything is going well, except that anything I type in nc gets echoed back.

Like this (Text in caps is response from server.  Mixed case is typed into nc):

```
    $ nc -U /var/run/ipc.sock
    READY
    Hello.
    Hello.
    OK
    Echo.
    Echo.
    OK
```

I can't figure out if this echoing of everything I type is some setting I missed in  my server code or if it's a setting for nc.  I've been through the net.createServer pages on nodejs.org and the manual page for nc on my FreeBSD server.  No luck.

This is the code for my server:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');

const socket = '/var/run/ipc.sock';

// ISO date-time stamp and a separator for logging.
function stamp(msg) {
  var d = new Date();
  return d.toISOString() + ' ' + msg;
}

// Create a Unix-domain IPC server to receive and execute commands.
const server = net.createServer((c) => {
  console.log(stamp('Client connect.'));
  c.write('READY\n');
  c.pipe(c);

  c.on('data', (d) => {
    if (d.slice(-1) == '\n') d = d.slice(0, -1);  // like Perl chomp()
    console.log(stamp('Data received: ' + d.toString()));
    c.write('OK\n');
  });

  c.on('end', () => {
    console.log(stamp('Client disconnect.'));
  });
});

// Start listening on a socket restricted to user:group.
server.listen(socket, () => {
  fs.chmod(socket, 0o660, (e) => {
    if (e) throw e;
  });
  console.log(stamp('Server listening.'));
});

// Error handler (specifically for stale socket due to unclean shutdown.)
server.on('error', (e) => {
  if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE')
    console.error('Stale socket detected. Remove ' + e.address + ' and try again.'
);
  else throw e;
});

// Catch SIGINT and SIGTERM in order to exit cleanly.
function sigHandler(s) {
  if (s == 'SIGINT' || s == 'SIGTERM') {
    console.log(stamp('Caught signal: ' + s + '.'));
    process.exit(0);
  }
}
process.on('SIGINT', sigHandler);
process.on('SIGTERM', sigHandler);

// Clean up socket on exit.
process.on('exit', (c) => {
  console.log(stamp('Shutdown.'));
  fs.unlink(socket, (e) => {
    console.error(stamp('Unable to remove socket ' + socket));
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using FreeBSD 12.1 is that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code:

```
c.pipe(c)
```

tells the stream `c` to send everything it receives right back on the same stream (echoing back everything it was sent).  Remove that line and it won't echo back everything.